# Exception in JDBC using MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to make an applicatio in java which has database in mysql. I have searched various sources on net and have included `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` in properties->library->add JAR/Library.

But it still shows me `java.lang.ClassNotFound Exception` when i run it.

I am using netbeans IDE 8.0 and jdk 1.7.0_45 and `mysql server 5.6`

Here is my code for jdbc mysql connection:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/prj","root","root");
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
    s=con.createStatement();
    String q="insert into call_log"+" values(now(),'room 1')";
    s.executeUpdate(q);
} catch(SQLException se) { 
    se.printStackTrace(); 
} catch(Exception e) { 
    System.out.println(e); 
} finally { 
    try { 
        if(con!=null) 
            con.close(); 
    } catch(SQLException se) { 
        se.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please.

Comment: here is complete code for jdbc

Comment: catch(SQLException se)
            {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                if(con!=null)
                con.close();
                }
                catch(SQLException se)
                {
                      se.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

Comment: The driver isn't on the runtime classpath. Note that `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` hasn't been necessary the last 15 years (it was a workaround for a bug in early MySQL JDBC drivers), and `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` hasn't been necessary since Java 6 (if you have a JDBC 4 compliant driver).

Comment: Then what to do if not using Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working in NetBeans 8.0.2

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DBConnect {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb", "user", "pass");
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
        String q = "select * from table";
        s.execute(q);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBConnect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>mavenproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: but this code is not working in my IDE and still showing class not found exception...

Comment: try to rebuild your project, or delete .m2 repository and download it again.

Comment: Are you using maven or ant?